# Wait for a job to finish before starting another job of same job group in quartz scheduler?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I am using Quartz scheduler to schedule jobs. I want

1. One job should wait for already running job if both jobs belong to the same job group
2. However 2 jobs can run parallel if job group is different

I thought of using ***Stateful Job*** but it disallows running parallel jobs of different groups also. While in ***@DisallowConcurrentExecution***, if *Jobdetail* object is different, it doesn't wait for first job to complete.

Comment: Have you figured it out?